# Android ellipse overflow priority

Tags: android, textview, ellipse

I have 2 textviews per horizontal linearlayout row on two rows. All the views are set as 0dp width and weight 1. They all have the same font and text size etc.
The views on the left side are gravity aligned left and the two on the right are gravity aligned right.

When both textviews text length overflow android always gives precedence to the textview on the right and ellipse the views on the left.

Is there a method that can be used to control which view ellipses when both views on the same row would not fit.

Ideally I want the views on the right to ellipse in favor of those on the left. Or failing that make them ellipse evenly per row.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't think there is a feature of order of the views to manage how they are measured.

you can customize the linearLayout by extending it in order to support this feature , but this is too hardcore for this task .

i would suggest putting the problematic views (those that take too much space and you don't with them to take too much space) into a new layout , and set its width to match_parent .

this way , it should take the rest of the space at the end of the measurements of the other views ,